# SQLIite column name has trailing parenthesis

Tags: python, sqlite

When I query my SQLite database, one of the column names returned has a trailing parenthesis. The database table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE 'transactions' ('user_id' bigint, 'symbol' text,'shares' integer, 'date' datetime)
```

I'm querying the the stocks owned by the logged in user.  I'm using `SUM(transactions.shares)` and `GROUP BY transactions.symbol` so that the number of shares is added up across multiple entries and organized by the specific stock symbol.

```
stocks_owned = db.execute("SELECT transactions.symbol, SUM(transactions.shares) FROM transactions WHERE user_id=:id GROUP BY transactions.symbol", id=session["user_id"])
```

`print(stocks_owned)` shows:

```
[{'symbol': 'ABC', 'shares)': 17}, {'symbol': 'ABT', 'shares)': 6}, {'symbol': 'BAB', 'shares)': 12}, {'symbol': 'BBC', 'shares)': 16}, {'symbol': 'BBN', 'shares)': 6}, {'symbol': 'DAX', 'shares)': 2}, {'symbol': 'SEA', 'shares)': 12}, {'symbol': 'SEE', 'shares)': 12}]
```

There is a parenthesis in the `shares` key: `'shares)'`, and it's causing problems accessing the value in a template. Why is this parenthesis there and how do I fix my query so it's not?

Comment: @Car - right, but the questions is, where does that typo come from? stocks_owned is being created by db.execute(...)

Comment: ah sorry! skimmed way too quickly. since the query is returning data for shares, it sounds like there's a parsing issue with `db.execute`. you can verify this by going into the database and looking at the table names, and verifying there isn't a rogue `)` in `shares`, and drilling down into the library's `db.execute` function to see where the `)` comes in (possibly easiest walking through it with a debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `)` is (somehow: suspect the `.` in the dbname prefix) coming from the closing paren in `SUM(transaction.shares)`. Add a column alias to the aggregate, ie `SUM(transaction.shares) shares`.

Comment: Wow, this solved the issue! Thank you. It works now with or without the "AS" when I do "SUM(transactions.shares) AS shares"